# ASP.NET Web API 2 Same Route Name Different POST Model Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

I'm trying to have two action methods on an API controller with the same [Route] name, but different parameter types. One which takes a particular object, and the other which takes an array of that object type.

The model binder doesn't seem to be able to distinguish between these and I get the following error returned:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request
```

Is there any way of having two POST methods with the same route but different parameter types?

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Why? What value will that add? it's just as simple to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 actions with same routing and same http verb (like Post). 
And I think that it's beter to use different routings for this example:

> /api/controllerName/PostType
>
> /api/controllerName/PostListType

it will be more readible and esier to mantain in future. And when someone else will create client app routing will be self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

using Route

```
[RoutePrefix("api/FooModule")]
public class FooController:ApiController
{

[Route("Get"),HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(){...}

[Route("GetOther"),HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetOther(){...}

}
```